# Signalr -> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'javascript:;' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm using asp.net core 2.2 angular with Signalr i get bellow issue in google chrome but in Firefox is working  also i added bellow code

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin();
                })); app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<BroadcastHub>("/notify");
            });
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'javascript:;' from origin  has been
>   blocked by CORS policy:  Cross origin requests are only supported for
>   protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS service would return an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both **`AllowAnyOrigin`** and **`AllowCredentials`** methods.

And **`AllowAnyOrigin`** is insecure, you can modify the code to allow specified origin, like below.

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
    builder
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithOrigins("http://example.com");
}));
```

Comment: If the issue only occurs in chrome, please share the version of your chrome, and if possible, please share a minimal, reproducible example, so that we can reproduce and troubleshoot it better.